# Retain only Decimal numbers in the data frame

Tags: r

I am having the data set as below,

```
1234     123.45    123.98    569.00
569.78   234.98    2347.1    898.11
689      598.1     569       781
```

Is it possible to retain only the decimals from the set:

```
123.45  123.98
569.78  234.98   2347.1   898.11
598.1
```

with R, I tried regex, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a dataframe we can use `lapply` and replace the values which match the regex with an empty space.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, !grepl("\\.", x), ""))

df
#      V1     V2     V3     V4
#1        123.45 123.98       
#2 569.78 234.98 2347.1 898.11
#3         598.1
```

---

If it is a vector a regex approach could be using `grep` and matching an exact "." in it.

```
grep("\\.", x, value= T) 
#[1] "123.45" "123.98" "569.78" "234.98" "2347.1" "898.11" "598.1"
```

This would convert the numbers into character, we can convert it into numeric by `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(grep("\\.", x,value= T))
#[1]  123.45  123.98  569.78  234.98 2347.10  898.11  598.10
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "1234     123.45    123.98    569.00
                         569.78   234.98    2347.1    898.11
                         689      598.1     569       781")

x <-c(1234, 123.45, 123.98, 569.00, 569.78, 234.98, 2347.1, 898.11, 689, 598.1, 569, 781)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use this:

```
tt <- c(1234, 123.45, 123.98, 569.00, 569.78, 234.98, 2347.1, 898.11, 689, 598.1, 569, 781)
tt[!(tt %% 1 == 0)]

123.45  123.98  569.78  234.98 2347.10  898.11  598.10
```

Comment: This requires that your vector is numeric; if it is a character vector, you can convert it to numeric via as.numeric.

Comment: Or `tt %% 1 != 0`  for one less function

Comment: oh yeah that is probably more elegant :-)

Answer (score 1):

We could also convert to `integer` and check with the original data

```
tt[as.integer(tt) != tt]
#[1]  123.45  123.98  569.78  234.98 2347.10  898.11  598.10
```